# GROUP BY Precedence in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables; one is called `rules` and the other `data`. The Rules table holds events, which have a `description`, `id` and `date_created` and is simply used to categorize events.

The `data` table has a `date` and `id` column; This stores the actual dates of an event, as events can span up to months long in dates.

My issue is this: I wish to select everything from `data` and group it by `date`, so each date is represented only once. However, *the event with the most recent creation date should have precedence* if there is a collision, i.e. two events happen on the same day. Here is what I've tried, which doesn't offer control over `date_created`:

`SELECT d.date, r.description FROM data d LEFT JOIN rules r ON d.id = r.id GROUP BY date ORDER BY d.date`

I haven't included `date_created` yet because I'm stuck, and not sure where it should go in the query to get the desired effect. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide data and desire result?

Comment: I'm on mobile currently but I'll try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems to me that at first you need to select maximum date of event creation and then using subquery you can desired result:

```
SELECT a.date, b.description
FROM data a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, description,MAX(date_created) as mdate
    FROM rules
    GROUP BY id,description
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.date = b.mdate
```